# Blank screen when accessing tty. Processes are dead on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: nvidia, 19.04, systemd, tty, 19.10

Whenver trying to access any tty1-6, I get a blank screen with a blinking cursor. Upon checking

`systemctl status getty@tty{1,2,3,4,5,6}`

All seem to return

```
● getty@ttyX.service - Getty on ttyX
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:agetty(8)
           man:systemd-getty-generator(8)
           http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html
```

I've tried restarting them with no luck. Some results I found online suggest it's a problem with the NVidia drivers, however I was unable to access them before logging in the DE (That's when the drivers are initialized as far as I understand).

This is what's logged when I try to access tty3, for example:

```
Sender: agetty
Time: 11:44:03
Message: /dev//dev/tty3: cannot open as standard input: No such file or directory
Audit Session: 2
Priority: 3
```

How should I proceed to getting them working back?

Answer (score 1):

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to wake up the `agetty` instance.